# Mule 4 - Replace a JSON value in JSON Array with Dataweave 2

Tags: arrays, json, mule, transform, dataweave

In my **Mule 4** flow I get a JSON Array similar to the following:

```
 [
     {
         "type": "error",
         "status": 404,
         "code": "not_found",
         "message": "Could not find the resource",
     },
     {
         "type": "error",
         "status": 401,
         "code": "",
         "message": "Could not find the specified ",
     }
 ]
```

I want to change the value of the `message` field to a `vars.germanMessage` variable for each JSON object.

I've tried to modify it with **Dataweave 2** this way:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
 ---
(payload as Array) map {

    "message": vars.germanMessage

}
```

But this returns a new JSON message with only the `message` field.

The input type is `Array<Object>` and output type too.

Is there any way to replace the value without changing the rest of the message?

Answer (score 4):

Yes just use mapObject

```
payload mapObject (value,key) -> {
    (key): if((key as String) == "message")) vars.germanMessage else value
}
```

Comment: Thanks @machaval, but the source payload is an `Array<Object>` like the output payload so, What map type should I use instead of `mapObject`?